# How to embed the javascript code in iframe tag? Trying to embed code in wix website using "Embed HTML"

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, velo

I want to run the below code under wix website through "Embed HTML". IFRAME does not allow scripts 
I want to embed custom HTML code on a third party utility like Wix.com or Wordpress.com which contains some javascript. After putting it as custom HTML in wix webpage, the embedded code does not work. It looks like the IFRAME is restricting the javascript code. The code to be embedded looks like given below. Can anyone please help me find a fix for it?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bit.ly/"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript"> var b2b = new B2B("35312623426f147b7073d4"); b2b.add("36603623426f147b7af5d7"); </script>`
`<label id="ybsAY9" for="b2b_call"></label>`
`<label id="9v0JZ3" for="b2b_sms"></label>` 
[Embedding Javascript code in Wix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e8pX.png)
[Wix IFrame Ispect SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWBaY.png)

[Wix IFrame Ispect SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWBaY.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution seems to be adding the Wix iframe but then replacing it with embedded head javascript through the Wix settings area in the main admin screen.
More details can be found here https://adsp2p.net/docs/addhtmltowix.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).